# Why aren't mapbox markers not styling properly with external data (CSV) file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have an external csv file providing data to my map using omnivore. I am trying to use L.mapbox.marker.icon styles to change the default "pin-drop" styling, but it continues to use the default styling (blue with white-dot center).

A portion of the code I'm using is below.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to style this?

```
var points = omnivore.csv('datelist.csv', {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-symbol': 'airport',
        'marker-color': '59245f'
    })
}).on('ready', function() {
    map.fitBounds(points.getBounds());
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        maxClusterRadius: 50
    });
    markers.addLayer(points);
    map.addLayer(markers);
    points.eachLayer(eachLayer);
});
```

Comment: marker styling is only available through the mapbox libary (it's not included in LeafletJS).  are you including mapbox.js and mapbox.css?

Comment: Yes, I've got them both in my head. I can paste the entirety of my code (its not large), if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option to `omnivore.csv` is options for the parser, not for the layer. You would move your style definition into the `ready` block and use [.setIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon) to change the marker icons.

Comment: I added the line `marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'airport','marker-color': '59245f'})` inside the brackets of `.on('read', function() {` but it's broken the whole map. I am still trying to figure out the correct syntax to implement your solution, but I'm not that knowledgable of JS.

Comment: I was missing an extra `)` so the map is no longer broken, but the points do not appear at all.

Comment: `marker` is not a variable in your code. You would do `points.eachLayer(function(marker) { marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'airport','marker-color': '59245f'}) })`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry you had to spell it out for me, but I appreciate the assistance. For posterity, the exact line of code I added was: `points.eachLayer(function(marker) { marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'airport','marker-color': '59245f'}) )});`